# Pandas sum (values from minutes to hour) time data values with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, time-series

I have a question: I want to sum time data values with Pandas. I have data in 15 minutes step and I want to sum the values for one hour.

For example: My Data

| Index | Date | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11.06.2021 | 04:00 | 1125.6 |
| 1 | 11.06.2021 | 04:15 | 5622.2 |
| 2 | 11.06.2021 | 04:30 | 3222.6 |
| 3 | 11.06.2021 | 04:45 | 2666.7 |
| 4 | 11.06.2021 | 05:00 | 4657.2 |
| 5 | 11.06.2021 | 05:15 | 2946.8 |
| 6 | 11.06.2021 | 05:30 | 3255.4 |
| 7 | 11.06.2021 | 05:45 | ... |
| 8 | 11.06.2021 | 06:00 | ... |
| 9 | 11.06.2021 | 06:15 | ... |
| 10 | 11.06.2021 | 06:30 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to have:

| Index | Date | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11.06.2021 | 4:00 | The sum from 4:00 to 4:45 |
| 1 | 11.06.2021 | 5:00 | ... |
| 2 | 11.06.2021 | 6:00 | ... |

This data is called `test`:

My soulution:

```
result = []
result1 = []
counter11 = 0
for index, row in test.iterrows():
    counter11 += 1
    print(counter11)
    result1 += test.values[index]
    result += result1
    if counter11 == 3:
        result.add(result.values)
        result = 0
        counter = 0
test["sum"] = result
```

I would be happy if somebody can help me. Thank you.

Comment: this wont be an appropriate way instead use a datetime column . refer [df.resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Comment: Edit the question to put the code in a code block.

Comment: Sorry, iam new at StackOverflow i must collect some Experience  with stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make yourself familiar with the [markdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

- concatenate `Date` and `Time` columns
- `pandas.to_datetime` to convert to datetime
- `set_index` to the Datetime
- `resample` for hours
- `sum` with `min_count=1` to o distinguish when there is no value for the period.

```
import pandas as pd

# creating the dataframe
import io
data = """
Index,Date,Time,Value
0,11.06.2021,04:00,1125.6
1,11.06.2021,04:15,5622.2
2,11.06.2021,04:30,3222.6
3,11.06.2021,04:45,2666.7
4,11.06.2021,05:00,4657.2
5,11.06.2021,05:15,2946.8
6,11.06.2021,05:30,3255.4
7,11.06.2021,07:30,1111.1
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',', usecols=['Date', 'Time', 'Value'])

# processing
df['Datetime']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+' '+df['Time'])
df.drop(['Date', 'Time'], axis=1, inplace= True)
df.set_index('Datetime', inplace= True)
print(df.resample('H').sum(min_count=1))

# output
                       Value
Datetime                    
2021-11-06 04:00:00  12637.1
2021-11-06 05:00:00  10859.4
2021-11-06 06:00:00      NaN
2021-11-06 07:00:00   1111.1
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your solution. I load a csv file and you declare data as a String. Can i use data_time also with a csv file?

Comment: @Jacek, I edited the answer to more closely match the creation of the dataframe from a csv file. replacing `io.StringIO(data)` by a filename should work. But this version suppose htat the file is in the form Index, Date, TimeValue. If it is not the case, please provide a subset of the file.

Comment: Subset of the File is Index, Date, Time, Value. Time and Value are separated

Comment: @Edited to match your change

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it works. My problem was that i use at the path place "" not ''

Comment: @Jacek : Added `min_count=1` in `sum` call to distinguish when there is no value for the period.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pandas I would like to make two suggestions.

First, you should make use of pandas builtin datetime, you can find everything about it in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html?highlight=datetime

This will make your life much easier when working with dates and times. You can use the datetime objects to create and index as in my code example below.

The second suggestions is, that once you are making use of pandas datetime, you can actually use other builtin functions such as resampling. This will 'group' the data in your dataframe based on some logic you provide to the function, such as resampling it by hour. Then you can apply functions to that resampled data such as sum().

```
import pandas as pd
#This is just for making this example, you will not need numpy
import numpy as np

"This creates a datetime index"
idx = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=70, freq="T")

"Creating a sample dataframe to work with"
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(1,70), index=idx, columns= ["Data"])

"""
This is what you are trying to do:
Resampling or 'grouping' the data by hours (in this case) and sums all
values for each hour.
"""
df.resample("H").sum()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your support. My problem is that i load the data from a csv File and you create data_time from scratch. I have the four Index | Date |Time | Value  in separately columns. You create the Data_Frame from scratch. I have a time series from 11.06.2021 to 11.12.2021 with 15 minuts time steps. How i can fix his problem with your code example without creating a sample dataframe